# Intent URL in mobile Chrome for testing multiple android package names

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, mobile-chrome

I'm using an intent URL to launch an app from mobile Chrome, or if the app is not installed fallback to a URL. It's described at https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents.

Now I have encountered an app that exists with two different package names.

Is there any URL syntax or other solution that lets me try two different package names before falling back to a URL?

The preferred solution would:

1. Try to open package name A.
2. If A does not exist, try to open package name B.
3. If neither was installed, go to fallback URL in mobile Chrome.

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to have multiple android packages! Could you tell me what app this is?

Comment: I tried it in my deleted answer. It does not work.

Comment: You mean: same app name and different package name?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But two completely different apps should be the same principle?

Comment: @gevert Can you share how you managed to solve this finally?

Answer (score 0):

there is no such syntax to let you do that.
But maybe some compromise solution can solve you problem.

1 you specify action instead of package

2 if you can't select the first solution,can you make two browser_fallback_url.The first browser_fallback_url just directly send a intent to open the APP B

Comment: Do you think you could provide an examples? Do you mean adding fallback url twice to the URL?

intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Furl1;S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Furl2;end

Answer (score 0):

So, I think one solution could be like this:

1. lets say you are in the webpage www.myweb.com/index.html
2. there you set the first intent, and as fallback the same URL www.myweb.com/index.html?number_of_tries=1 (adding a parameter, could be anything)
3. in the javascript code you can understand that if that parameter is present, then mean you have to try the second package
4. call second intent and as fallback use your real fallback URL www.myweb.com/my_real_fallback.html (for example)

Comment: I've tried using a webpage in between to chain multiple intent links, but it didn't work for me. The mobile chrome browser just ended up doing nothing. Did you mange to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have **three** URLs, say URL1, URL2, URL3.

1. URL1 tries to open package name A. If A doesn't exist, redirect to URL2.
2. URL2 tries to open package name B. If B doesn't exist, redirect to URL3.
3. URL3 simply opens in default browser.

Comment: I've tried using an intent url as fallback, but it didn't work for me. The mobile chrome browser ended up doing nothing. Do you have an example URL by any chance?